# How can I add a custom class to only nav sub-menu > li > a items in WordPress?

Tags: php, menus, navigation

I've this DOM here:

```
<ul class="sub-menu">
    <li id="menu-item-1424" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat">
        <a href="#">Item</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

What I need to do is, to add a custom class (`has-ripple`) to only the `sub-menu > a` items:

```
<ul class="sub-menu">
    <li id="menu-item-1424" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat">
        <a href="#" class="has-ripple">Item</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

This is what I've tried:

```
add_filter( 'nav_menu_link_attributes', 'nav_menu_link_class', 10, 3 );
function nav_menu_link_class( $atts, $item, $args ) {
    $class         = 'has-ripple';
    $atts['class'] = $class;

    return $atts;
}
```

This works but it also add the class to non-submenu a items outside of the dropdown. So how can I do this right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be applied to sub-menu items only, your code should be:

```
add_filter( 'nav_menu_link_attributes', 'nav_menu_link_class', 10, 2 );
function nav_menu_link_class( $atts, $item ) {
    if( !$item->has_children && $item->menu_item_parent > 0 ) {
        $class         = 'has-ripple';
        $atts['class'] = $class;
    }

    return $atts;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this  : **[Documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/nav_menu_link_attributes/#user-contributed-notes)**

```
add_filter( 'nav_menu_link_attributes', 'nav_menu_link_class', 10, 4 );

function nav_menu_link_class(  $atts, $item, $args, $depth ) {

      if ( 0 !== $depth ) {
         $class         = 'has-ripple';
         $atts['class'] = $class;
      }
    return $atts;
}
```

I hope this may help.

Comment: Where `$depth` does come from?

Comment: $depth is 4th parameter passed to callback. Mistake corrected and answer updated. Thanks for helpful reminding!

Comment: Then `add_filter` should specify 4 parameters for callback function.

Comment: You are right. Thanks, once again.

Comment: What if WordPress version is lower than 4.1.0 ?

Comment: In that case your answer can be a solution.